# Setup FreeRadius + ldap + single sign-on

Tags: ldap, single-sign-on, freeradius

Am trying to configure Single sign-on using FreeRadius.

Scenario:
I have a fully configured LDAP (389 DS) Version-2.1 with few users and groups (in CentOS6).
I have installed FreeRadius (latest stable version) (in CentOS 6).
Configured FreeRadius to listen the above LDAP server.

I have made a client system (CentOS6) as radius client using pam_radius module. Now, am able to login to NAS with the LDAP credentials and getting logs correctly in FreeRadius.

Now, I want to implement single sign-on in this setup since I want to added some other devices like Firewall(Sonicwall) to authenticate.

I couldn't find any good docs to configure this.

Can someone please suggest me how to configure Single sign-on in the above setup?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For firewalls most people just use the accounting data to start and stop sessions as appropriate. This is usually triggering a script from within the `accounting {}` section of the freeradius server, creating the session on `Acct-Status-Type == Start` and destroying it on `Acct-Status-Type == Stop`.

If the PAM module sends Interim-Updates, you can record those in a database, and also set a 'lastupdated' timestamp. You then have a cronjob to check for rows  where `NOW() - lastupdated > (interim-interval * 2)`, and for those rows, delete the session on the firewall and close out the session in the database.

There is no proper SSO mechanism I know of which runs purely over RADIUS, the Project Moonshot guys were trying to get something working with SAML and a special EAP method, but it's probably too complex for what you want here, and not supported by PAM anyway.

Comment: Arran, 
Thanks for your time and reply to this.
I want some session keeping mechanism like Kerberos. 
Earlier I tried FreeIPA which takes care of LDAP as well as Kerberos setup. So, if I create the users, group and hosts it will automatically enables SSO. Since our firewall(Sonicwall) does not supports FreeIPA, I forced to choose FreeRadius.
So, is there any other way to make FreeRadius as SSO?
Once again thanks for your valuable reply.

Comment: No. FreeRADIUS does not support any SSO mechanisms. It does have a rlm_krb5 module which implements kerberos, but there's no mechanism to return the TGT back to the authenticating client. That's the problem.

Comment: Hmmm.. Then in which way the FreeRadius relates with SSO? 
Please excuse if it is a silly question since am very new to RADIUS.

Comment: It generally doesn't. It's not just FreeRADIUS there are no widely deployed SSO mechanisms for RADIUS or EAP.