# Single sign on using freeRadius and Apache?‏

Tags: apache, freeradius

I have seen the answer to this question

[Setup FreeRadius + ldap + single sign-on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23474793/setup-freeradius-ldap-single-sign-on)

the answer is helpful, but what about Apache case, How to pass the credentials to Apache? or How to configure Apache to accept only users who already authenticated by freeradius?

In details:

I'm authenticating users in the wired network (clients connected to a Nortel switch) using ieee802.1x and freeradius,it worked will, but when a user ask for an authorized web page it will ask him for the credentials for the second time:

Is there a way to configure freeRADIUS and Apache to let the authorized users using 802.1x to get the web pages (which needs authentication) without asking them to type it for a second time (something like single sign on)? In short words can we pass the credentials from freeradius to Apache? Is there any tutorials that will help me in freeRADIUS website?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short Answer**
No, not as you're describing.

**Long Answer**
The credentials that your users are providing to the network layer to authenticate their access to their ports are not available to your users' web browsers. Without them, the web browsers can't automatically provide them to your web server, and that's why your users have to provide them again to login to your web sites.

**Options**
If we allow ourselves to get creative for a bit, there are some technology options you may have to provide the kind of sign-on functionality you are seeking.

1. **Client certificates**
   Both 802.1x and Apache support the use of client certificates to authentication users. In this scheme, you would generate a common user certificate for each user that would be used for both 802.1x authentication and web server authentication. the certificate would probably have to be configured in two different systems, but to the user, if they got on the network they would not need to do anything more to auth with your web server.
2. **Special-purpose Browser Plug-in**
   Conceivably, you could develop a special browser plug-in and related application that would control   accepting a username and password and then provide them to both the 802.1x auth system and the web site.  Security would be questionable in that controlling app.
3. **IP-Based Authentication**
   If you're assigning each user an IP address on your network, you can allow access to the IP ranges and write a custom module to query the IP address and associate it with a user. It's essentially authentication by IP address where the IP address acts as a proxy for the username. It requires that you setup your RADIUS server to keep track of which users are assigned which IPs at any given time.

**Links**
For certificate setups, you can use the links below to guide you. For the other two items, they're conceptual/theoretical. You'll have to write some code or find some preimplemented code to do what they describe.

- [802.1x Infrastructure TechNet article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/networking/archive/2012/05/30/creating-a-secure-802-1x-wireless-infrastructure-using-microsoft-windows.aspx) - pay attention to the EAP-TLS section
- [Apache Client Authentication and Access Control](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/ssl/ssl_howto.html#accesscontrol) - using the information

Comment: Thanks for your answer it is perfect, but can you edit your answer to provide me with links about the three options

Comment: and could you explain the third option more than that

Comment: If each IP is assigned to a single user, then when the IP talks to the web server, the web server can determine which user is talking to it by looking at the IP address. You need to develop some way for FreeRADIUS to store the IP-to-user mappings in a way that Apache can look it up via a custom auth handler.

Comment: I have stored IP and USER in mysql DB and as DNS records , Is there a way that Apache can make use of one of them?, how can we build a custom auth using mysql or DNS?

Comment: Look at mod_perl. mod_perl allows you write any Apache handler (including auth handlers) in Perl, and Perl can very easily interact with MySQL or DNS.

Comment: can you give me a little example of how can I make use of  mod_perl?

Comment: It's best to read the documentation: http://perl.apache.org/docs/2.0/user/handlers/http.html

Comment: Just to add, it's also theoretically possible to use shared session tickets between Apache and FreeRADIUS, but it'd likely require code modifications on both sides.